# Shortcut on client to run bat file on a server

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Is it possible to place a shortcut on a client which will run a bat (or vbscript) file on a server?  (as opposed to the script running on the client)

It seems pretty basic, but I'm at a loss how this would be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an excellent suite of tools called PsTools which includes [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). PsExec allows you to remotely execute programs on another machine (or in this case a server). You have to have the appropriate authority/credentials to do so of course.

The following psexec command would run the batch file my_batch_file.bat located in directory "C:\batch" (on the server) as user 'johndoe' with account password 'Asdf1234' on server with name 'ServerName':

```
psexec \\ServerName -u johndoe -p Asdf1234 c:\batch\my_batch_file.bat
```

Note that the batch file would have to exist on the server already in this example.

Read more about PsExec here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great option.  Since I posted I started going to iis route to run the file, since iis happens to be running on the server already.  If that causes me any trouble I'll use psexec.